# Handling popup with many buttons using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I'm using Selenium web driver with Java language. When there are two buttons in a popup i.e. ok and cancel , it can be easily handled with web driver using the following code:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept(); // or alert.dismiss(); depending upon the action you want to perform.
```

But what to do when there are more than two buttons, i.e. there are 3 to 4 buttons in the pop up ( e.g. like ok, cancel, try again, ignore/continue)? How can we click on whichever button that we want?

Comment: I believe we have to use AUTOIT tool for it.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, user1924504. Could you elaborate on this restriction? What factors cause you to use it? Is it the only option available, or are there other factors in your workplace that mandate it?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the sendkeys function from the alert class to either press the shortcut key to select the item you want or tab to the correct item and press enter.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem like the Selenium Alert class allows you to click a specific item, which would be much more useful...

Comment: This seems to be a nice idea. Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the Selenium [AdvancedUserInteractions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)?

Are you using CSS style sheets and/or page objects?  It's very simple to select a single option from multiple choices using either of those and defining the buttons as [WebElements](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

```
element1.click() // (if you're using Java)
element2.click()
```

etc.